# What does it mean to send CAN messages at 10Hz or 100Hz? Is this configurable on Linux SocketCAN

Tags: can, linux, socket

I understand the meaning of message transfer speed, i.e. a theoretical maximum of 1Mbit/second, and the 8Mbit/second in the CAN FD.

That's essentially the rate at which bits are travelling on the copper for a lack of better description.

What I don't understand is the 10Hz and 100Hz that I see in some links like [this](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros_canopen/issues/285).  I looked at the Linux kernel docs for [SocketCAN](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/can.html#netlink-interface-to-set-get-devices-properties) where it talks about the device properties, such as Clock Frequency.

It seems that this message rate is somehow configurable but I am not sure how to go about that.

Comment: It is common that machine/car etc control systems send CAN frames repetitively once every 10ms or 100ms etc. The whole real-time behavior of the bus will depend on this and it enables bus load calculations to be deterministic. How that makes sense in Linux, I have no idea, since Linux can't be used for real-time systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually called the broadcast rate, how often you send that message on the bus, e.g. how fast a vehicle is moving should be sent fairly often, but the coolant temperature will not change very often, so can be sent far less frequently.

Comment: Makes sense! How can I manage that in c/c++ code?

Comment: It appears to be covered under the section "Broadcast Manager"